# SQL Group By Query Optimization

Tags: postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

Initially, the below query was taking 9 seconds. So I added indices to every `JOIN` and `WHERE` fields. Still, the query taking 2.062 seconds.

Can we optimize it more?

```
SELECT units.contract_id,
       count(units.property_id) AS contract_property_count,
       sum(units.number_of_units) AS number_of_units
FROM (
       SELECT c.id AS contract_id,
              p.id AS property_id,
              p.number_of_units
       FROM contracts c
            JOIN contract_properties cp ON (c.id = cp.contract_id)
            JOIN properties p ON (cp.property_id = p.id)
       WHERE c.contract_status_type_id IN (10, 11) AND
             (cp.termination_date IS NULL OR
             cp.termination_date > NOW()) AND
             p.cid IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY c.id,
                p.id,
                p.number_of_units
     ) AS units
GROUP BY units.contract_id
```

**Edit 1:**
Adding EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"HashAggregate  (cost=104307.65..104309.65 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=1823.330..1830.413 rows=25653 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: c.id"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=89488.81..94877.48 rows=538867 width=12) (actual time=1655.332..1749.694 rows=219689 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: c.id, p.id, p.number_of_units"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=18388.58..85447.31 rows=538867 width=12) (actual time=249.417..1326.080 rows=739675 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (cp.property_id = p.id)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2353.07..62002.38 rows=538867 width=8) (actual time=25.870..754.424 rows=739696 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (cp.contract_id = c.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on contract_properties cp  (cost=0.00..51215.32 rows=812084 width=8) (actual time=0.006..455.507 rows=809944 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: ((termination_date IS NULL) OR (termination_date > now()))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 432549"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=1852.85..1852.85 rows=40018 width=4) (actual time=25.561..25.561 rows=39902 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1915kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on contracts c  (cost=0.00..1852.85 rows=40018 width=4) (actual time=0.010..18.071 rows=39902 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (contract_status_type_id = ANY ('{10,11}'::integer[]))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 20408"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=13133.00..13133.00 rows=232200 width=8) (actual time=222.430..222.430 rows=232186 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 262144  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11059kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on properties p  (cost=0.00..13133.00 rows=232200 width=8) (actual time=0.021..161.746 rows=232186 loops=1)"
"                          Filter: (cid IS NOT NULL)"
"Planning time: 1.962 ms"
"Execution time: 1836.366 ms"
```

Comment: What is the inner `GROUP BY` for? Looks like an obfuscated `DISTINCT` to me, for no aggregation function is used. But then, the records should be distinct already, or can you have duplicates in `contract_properties`?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Have duplicates in `contract_properties`.